# Parallel Invoke is taking too long to launch

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I need some advice.  I have an application that processes trade information from a real-time data feed from the stock exachanges.  My processing is falling behind.

Since I'm running on a 3GHz Intel I7 with 32 GBytes of main memory, I should have enough power to do this application.  The Parse routine stores trade information in an SQL Server 2014 database, running on a Windows 2012 R2 Server.

I put the following timing information in the main processing loop:

```
  invokeTime.Restart();

  Parallel.Invoke(() => parserObj.Parse(julian, data));

  invokeTime.Stop();
  var milliseconds = invokeTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  if (milliseconds > maxMilliseconds) {
    maxMilliseconds = milliseconds;
    messageBar.SetText("Invoke: " + milliseconds);
  }
```

I'm getting as much as 1122 milliseonds to do the Parallel.Invoke.  A similar timing test shows that the Parse routine only takes 7 milliseconds (max).

Is there a better way of processing the data, other than doing the Parallel.Invoke?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Charles

Comment: Why are you calling `Parallel.Invoke` with only one delegate?

Comment: This might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10802333/2638872 Looks like other people have wondered the same thing.

Comment: Not enough information to do much but guess. How many of these threads are running concurrently? It takes time for the OS to spin up a new pool thread if there isn't one waiting in the wings. You might look into [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx). Also, if you have too many threads running, everything's going to slow down.

Comment: The posted code does nothing in parallel. Use Task.Start() or Threadpool.QueueUserWorkitem().

Comment: Reed Copsey should read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/634146/Background-Thread-Let-me-count-the-ways

Comment: @CBrauer - The parallel.Invoke() example on that page is useless too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
 parserObj.Parse(julian, data));
});
```

How does your Parse method look like? Maybe the bottleneck is in there...

Comment: If you do that then you're effectively timing doing nothing, as you're never waiting for the operation to complete.  There's also still no parallelization here, as there is only one unit of work to be done.

Comment: This is a question looking for clarification, so should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Servy - the time-measurement would be worthless but the core business might profit a lot.

Comment: @HenkHolterman When there is only one single unit of work to be done running it in a new thread, and then doing nothing productive in the original thread gains nothing.  Now if we actually knew more details about what is actually being done here, a sensible answer to whether, or possibly how, it could be parallelized might be able to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

In Stephen Toub's article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx he describes: "Task.Run can and should be used for the most common cases of simply offloading some work to be processed on the ThreadPool".  That's exactly what I want to do, offload the Parse rosutine to a background thread. So I changed:

Parallel.Invoke(() => parserObj.Parse(julian, data));

to:

Task.Run(() => parserObj.Parse(julian, data));

I also increased the number of threads in the ThreadPool from 8 to 80 by doing:

```
    int minWorker, minIOC;;
    ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out minWorker, out minIOC);
    var newMinWorker = 10*minWorker;
    var newMinIOC = 10*minIOC;
    if (ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(newMinWorker, newMinIOC)) {
      textBox.AddLine("The minimum no. of worker threads is now: " + newMinWorker);
    } else {
      textBox.AddLine("Drat! The minimum no. of worker threads could not be changed.");
    }
```

The parsing loop, which runs for 6 1/2 hours/day, looks like:

```
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    var maxMilliseconds = 0L;
    while ((data = GetDataFromIQClient()) != null) {
      if ( MarketHours.IsMarketClosedPlus2() ) {
        break;
      }
      stopWatch.Restart();

      Task.Run(() => parserObj.Parse(julian, data));

      stopWatch.Stop();
      var milliseconds = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
      if (milliseconds > maxMilliseconds) {
        maxMilliseconds = milliseconds;
        messageBar.SetText("Task.Run: " + milliseconds);
      }
    }
```

Now, the maximum time spent to call Task.Run was 96 milliseconds, and the maximum time spent in parser was 18 milliseconds. I'm now keeping up with the data transmission.

Charles